# API call leads to pending promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, node.js-got

I am attempting to store an API call response into the variable `cat`. When I execute the following code, the console logs `Promise { <pending> }`. Why is this occuring?

```
const got = require('got');

let dog = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await got('https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/coins/btc-bitcoin');
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.body);
        //=> 'Internal server error ...'
    }
}

let cat = dog();
console.log(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dog()` will return a promise because it is an async function.
You can get the value like that:

```
let cat = await dog();
```

OR

```
dog().then((cat)=>{
  // do something here with the response
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const got = require('got');

let dog = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await got('https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/coins/btc-bitcoin');
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.body);
        //=> 'Internal server error ...'
    }
}

let cat = dog();
console.log(cat)
```

In your code, `response` is a promise. I expect your price data is being returned as JSON so you need to add `return await response.json()` which will instead return a JSON object you can print out to the console.